# Layout goes over recycler view instead of pushing it above

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a fragment that has a recycler view and a layout containing an edit text at the bottom. The edit text has min height of 50dp and max of 100dp. When I have scrolled to the last item in the recycler view, I want the recycler view to be pushed above, instead of the edit text going over the recycler view. Also, when I click the edit text, the recycler view does not display the last message

[Gif of problem](https://jmp.sh/7ifSfwxG)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.fragments.ChatMessageFragment">

`The Recycler View'
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvChatMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayoutEditTextHolder"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

`Layout that holds the edit text'
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutEditTextHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvChatMessage">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivProfilePicSender"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profilepic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/send_24px"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextChatMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_box"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Message @john_doe"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivSendMessage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivProfilePicSender"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The constraint layout that the edit text is in is already constrained to the recycler view.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Recyclerview to be pushed above, you should set it to be above the 'Layout that contains the edit text'.

Assuming your parent layout is RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout>

// The recyclerview => set `android:layout_above="@+id/constraintLayout6"`

// Layout that contains the edit text => with id 'constraintLayout6'

</RelativeLayout>
```

this should work. let me know if it helps

Comment: Tried this, same issue. Originally, parent layout was constraint layout and the recycler view was constrained above the 'Layout that contains the edit text'

Comment: share complete xml code.

Comment: edited the post to display entire xml code